# Facebook Marketing API Custom Audiences - Where/How do I collect EXTERN_ID value?

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I have an existing Facebook Marketing API Custom Audience integration where I push contact information for matching and it is working appropriately.

I would like to be able to target facebook users via offline website traffic segments, using the Custom Audience EXTERN_ID field.

I have yet to find a place that explains where/how to collect/set the EXTERN_ID when someone visits my site, so that I can target them later. Can I pass EXTERN_ID in the Facebook Pixel call?

Comment: EXTERN_ID is any ID you want it to be. As explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api/